# Java button within graphics panel

Tags: java, user-interface, button, graphics

I'm relatively new to developing GUI's within java so this may well be a stupid question or quite simply not possible to achieve but here we go.

I've created 1 single JPanel with no border layout set up or anything like that and I intended to paint a GUI on top of it using the graphics class. The JPanel is just plain black and then I've drawn a huge box over it leaving the black just as a border, and painted the whole GUI within this white box.

I want to add buttons within that white box GUI as well but I've no idea how. In fact they don't even have to be traditional buttons JButtons, if I could just draw a shape and have that act as a button then add an event handler to just that shape that would work also but I don't know how I'd do that either.

I have so much code for my whole program (it's a school coursework project) that I'm not sure which parts would even be worth sharing to assist with this question since there's so many GUI aspects I've already drawn so I've tried to just explain my issue in words.

Honestly I have no clue what I'm doing so any help would be appreciated.

EDIT: Here's a screenshot of my current GUI with a 'sketch' of how and where I'd like to be able to add buttons.

[GUI Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FcGS6.png)

Comment: You can edit your question and add a sketch describing how exactly you want the view to look; that'd make it easier to help you. You can tag me in the comments after you've edited your question. Good luck!

Comment: Honestly, I have no idea what the question actually is

Comment: @Taslim an image should be there now, just click that link, I hope it sort of helps?

Comment: The right side is just a `JTable` and supporting footer (panel and labels).  The graph and buttons can be separated into to classes/components, with the buttons simply been laid out using a `FlowLayout` or some such.

Answer (score 0):

As with any suitably complex UI, you need to start by breaking it down into manageable chunks, focusing on areas of mutual interaction and functionality.

For example...

[image: Part 01]

Says to me that you have two primary UI elements, the left and the right.

This could easily be established with a `GridLayout`, but, if the two sides are not equal in width, a `GridBagLayout` might be more appropriate

[image: Part 02]

The right side to me says simply, `JTable`.  You could place this within a container using a `BorderLayout`, allowing the table to occupy the `CENTER` position.

The key information would then a component laid out with either a `GridLayout` (top and bottom) or a `GridBagLayout` if the requirements are more complex.  This component would then be added to the `SOUTH` position of the `BorderLayout`.

[image: Part 03]

Again, this is pretty simple.  The primary layout would probably be a `BoderLayout`, with the title in the `NORTH` position, the graph in the `CENTER` and the buttons wrapped in a component in the `SOUTH`.

You could use either a `FlowLayout` or `GridBagLayout` to layout the buttons depending on your how you want them to appear

## Recommendations

Have a look at:

- [Laying Out Components Within a Container](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html)
- [How to Use Tables](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html)

And for the "border", I'd recommend you have a look at `LineBorder`.  Take a look at [How to use Borders](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/border.html) more details

Comment: Thank you for this. However I've tried this but as soon as I start messing around with GridLayouts and adding new containers I get a Null Pointer Error on my paint method which is beyond me.